# MAX aggregate within a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data

```
 GROUP_ID   INDEX
   NULL       1
     1        2
   NULL       3
     1        4
   NULL       5
     2        6
     2        7
```

What I want is to get a field that contains:

- if group_id IS NOT NULL, a smallest index in that group
- if group_id IS NULL, then index from that row

The result dataset for the above example would be:

```
 GROUP_ID   INDEX  GROUP_INDEX_MIN
   NULL       1          1
     1        2          2
   NULL       3          3
     1        4          2
   NULL       5          5
     2        6          6
     2        7          6
```

In Oracle I would resolve this by using `(CASE WHEN group_id IS NOT NULL THEN MIN(index) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) ELSE group_id END)`, but since MySQL does not support that, I really don't know how to proceed :) I can solve this by using a subquery that retrieves minimal values for each group and then left joining to it, but I think that there must be a more elegant solution.

If you need any more information, please ask.
Thanks.

Comment: In your answer the table contains redundant GROUP_INDEX_MIN repeats. I'd suggest revising this design. Perhaps two independent queries would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an inline view representing the min Group_index_min (minT) and then join to it and do a coalesce between group_ID and the min

```
SELECT t.group_id, 
       t.index, 
       Coalesce(t.group_id, minTgroup_index_min) group_index_min 
FROM   yourtable t 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT group_id, 
                         MIN(index) group_index_min 
                  FROM   yourtable
                  GROUP BY 
                         group_id) minT 
         ON t.group_id = minT.group_id
```

Comment: Actually I already did something similar to that, I was wondering if there was a solution that does not include two queries to main table?

Comment: no there isn't but if your indexes are good the perf should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you only want to find the minimum `INDEX` values for every group, without having to output the entire table and thus repeat the non-NULL `GROUP_ID`s, you could try the following query:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_ID,
  MIN(`INDEX`) AS GROUP_INDEX_MIN
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  GROUP_ID,
  CASE WHEN GROUP_ID IS NULL THEN `INDEX` ELSE GROUP_ID END
```

It should return something like this:

```
GROUP_ID  GROUP_INDEX_MIN
--------  ---------------
NULL      1
NULL      3
NULL      5
1         2
2         6
```

That is, as I said, the repetition of non-NULL `GROUP_ID` values is suppressed.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I have to output entire table without eliminating any of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
SELECT a.group_id, a.index, (CASE WHEN a.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN a.group_index_min ELSE a.index END) group_index_min 
FROM (
SELECT 
    p.group_id, p.index,
    (CASE WHEN @group <> IFNULL(p.group_id, 0) THEN @n := p.index ELSE @n := @n END) group_index_min, 
    @group := IFNULL(p.group_id, 0) 
FROM
    temp p
ORDER BY p.group_id, p.index
) A
ORDER BY
  (CASE WHEN a.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN a.group_index_min ELSE a.index END)
```

This works for my example, sorting values by their index (if they don't belong to a group) or by group index (if they do belong in a group). Now to try to apply to to my real tables/data :)

If somebody is willing to look this up and say if it contains some of MySQL DONT's I'd much appreciate it. As I said, I'm not a MySQL expert so I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: While I agree with @ypercube, at least your solution *can* be improved so as to make it simper. Here's my attempt at doing so:
`SELECT 
    p.\`index\`,
    (CASE WHEN @group = p.group_id THEN @n ELSE @n := p.\`index\` END) group_index_min, 
    (@group := p.group_id) group_id
FROM
    temp p
ORDER BY p.group_id, p.\`index\``. As you can see, the `group_id` column had to be relocated to the end of the column list. If that matters to you, you could select from the result set, putting the columns in the required order.

Answer (score 0):

One more try:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_ID
  , `INDEX` 
  , COALESCE( ( SELECT MIN(ti.GROUP_INDEX_MIN)
                FROM TableX AS ti
                WHERE ti.GROUP_ID = t.GROUP_ID
              )
            , t.GROUP_INDEX_MIN 
            ) AS GROUP_INDEX_MIN 
FROM
    TableX AS t
ORDER BY
    GROUP_INDEX_MIN
```

Answer (score 0):

The joined "PreQuery" is done for all groups including that of the NULL entries.  So, a left-join is not even required.  However, applying the "CASE/WHEN" will still see the "NULL" entry from the original source and use that as basis to get the MinIndex (when not null), or just use its own index position (when it was null)

```
select 
      YT.Group_ID,
      YT.`Index`,
      CASE WHEN YT.GROUP_ID IS NULL 
         THEN YT.`Index` 
         ELSE YT2.MinIndex END as Group_Index_Min
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN ( select YT2.Group_ID,
                       MIN( YT2.`Index` ) MinIndex
                    from YourTable YT2
                    group by YT2.Group_ID ) YTMin
            on YT.Group_ID = YTMin.Group_ID
```